# Javascript Drag and Drop Grid

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop

I'm looking for a script that would allow me to have a grid of draggable divs (used to organize [image thumbnails](http://imgfave.com/?view=thumb)). So when one div is dragged over another, the divs would shift to create an empty spot to drop the div.

I know jQuery has a drag and drop lib, but it doesn't seem to allow for the functionality I need (snapping to a grid and moving of surrounding divs).

Anyone know of a script or framework that has what I need?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Have a look at the [JQuery](http://www.jquery.com) and more specifically, [JQuery UI](http://ui.jquery.com/) since it has "draggable", "droppable", "sortable", and a variety of other complex components.

Here is the specific example of a [drag and drop grid](http://ui.jquery.com/demos/sortable#floating) you're looking for.

Comment: That's not a grid that is a sortable list.  While you could perceivably turn a list into a grid like object, it is not the same

Comment: Unless you're using a table, a grid is just a series of elements that happen to line up with a set of headings.  Based on the links given, I'd say the answer still stands.  Especially given the fact that I've used it to solve the exact problem the OP is talking about several times.

Answer (score 5):

Not specifically for images, but could certainly be used that way, but http://gridster.net/ looks pretty nice for being able to drag and drop items and have them re-shuffle to fit.

Comment: does it work for you in chrome? for me it only works in ie

Answer (score 5):

5 years later, I think this is what you were looking for: https://github.com/uberVU/grid

Answer (score 4):

Maybe my **REDIPS.drag** library will be helpful. It uses table (one or many) as a dropping grid. Any DIV element with class="drag" will be able to drag across table cells. Library also have option to write JS code for events like: drop, clone, delete, move ... it's flexible and easy to use, here is link to the demo page:

http://www.redips.net/my/preview/REDIPS_drag/

Comment: Please mention in your answers that you're affiliated with the product you're recommending. As mentioned in the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion).

Comment: This rule was unknown to me and I have corrected my answer - thanks!

Comment: @dbunic, thanks a lot! This is exactly what I was looking for :D I don't know much about JS, but with your lib I should be able to do everything I need :) Awesome!

Answer (score 2):

Another option would be [jQuery.Shapeshift](http://mcpants.github.io/jquery.shapeshift/); it's much like [Gridster.js](http://gridster.net/), but more adaptable.

Comment: Pity both of them seems to be in that semi-abandoned state one so often sees on github :(